# TFS to VSO Migration Missing Changes

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Using version 1.3.1.000 of the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility I successfully (556/556 changesets/labels, 0 retry) migrated a project to VSO.  To validate the process I did a file comparison between a fresh Get Latest of the project from TFS and VSO and found differences.

Here is the history on the file that was different:

TFS

[image: TFS Changesets]

VSO
[image: VSO Changesets]

It looks like your utility did not correctly handle this change.  Is this a known issue?  Is there anything I can do to get around it?

Comment: Hi Ryan,

Can you please check for the following:
1. Is the changeset 3399 moving file to some other project in TFS?
2. If its the case, than is that other project was selected for migration from TFS to VSO?

If the file is moved to another project and that project is not selected for migration during configuration, than file changes done in the other project, would not get migrated. So, please confirm the scenario.

Regards,
OpsHub Support

Comment: I checked the details of changesets 3399, 3390 & 3291 and they only affected files in the project I was migrating.

Comment: Was the file been merged before? How did you get the changeset 3289 and 3291? I mean delete and then add.

Comment: @RyanMathewson, please share the OpsHubTFSService.log file in the folder: C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs

Comment: Hi Ryan, Lets have the communication via email. Please contact us at support@opshub.com and the agent would contact you for the case. Regards, OpsHub Support

Comment: I can't release the logs without sanitizing the information first and that would be too much work.  We ended up abandoning the history and just manually checking in the changes.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Please drop an email at support@opshub.com if you face any issues during migration.